# Error occurred while decoding OAEP Padding C#

Tags: c#, encryption

Below is my code and error is in the Title. I encrypted using private key but I decrypt using the same private key I ran into the error mentioned in the title, not really sure what is the underlying cause of the error. Any help in that regard will be highly appreciated.

```
Class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string thumbPrint = "SomeValue";
       EncryptUserName("Steve", thumbPrint, true, true);
    }
    public static void EncryptUserName(string textToEncript, string certificateThumbprint, bool searchLocalMachine, bool searchUser)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = FindCertificate(certificateThumbprint, searchLocalMachine, searchUser);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] cipherData = rsaEncryptor.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncript), true);
        var encryptedString  = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherData);
        Console.WriteLine(encryptedString);
    }
    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, bool fOAEP, X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (encryptedData == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptedData");
        }
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }
        if (certificate.PrivateKey == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Certificate provided has no private key");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(certificate.PrivateKey);
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey)
        {
            return provider.Decrypt(encryptedData, fOAEP);
        }
    }

    public static string CertificateDecrypt(string textToDecript, string certificateThumbprint, bool searchLocalMachine, bool searchUser)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = FindCertificate(certificateThumbprint, searchLocalMachine, searchUser);
        byte[] bytesArray = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecript);
        //Decrypt(bytesArray, true, certificate);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(bytesArray, true, certificate));
    }
    public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, string thumbprint)
    {
        X509Store store = null;
        X509Certificate2 certificate2;
        try
        {
            store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Enumerator enumerator = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false).GetEnumerator();
            X509Certificate2 current = null;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                current = enumerator.Current;
            }
            certificate2 = current;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (store != null)
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
        return certificate2;
    }
    private static X509Certificate2 FindCertificate(string certificateThumbprint, bool searchLocalMachine, bool searchUser)
    {
        certificateThumbprint = certificateThumbprint.Replace(" ", "");
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
        if (searchUser)
        {
            certificate = LoadCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, certificateThumbprint);
        }
        if (searchLocalMachine && (certificate == null))
        {
            certificate = LoadCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, certificateThumbprint);
        }
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Certificate with thumbprint {certificateThumbprint} cannot be loaded (not found)");
        }
        return certificate;
    }
}
```

Comment: A padding error can mean any number of things: wrong key, wrong encoding, incomplete/overfull ciphertext. You should show the encryption code, give the example values that you've used and show the full stacktrace. Otherwise, it would be plain guessing what might be wrong with this code (or the encryption code). In short, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You were right there was some problem with the ciphertext. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Error occurred while decoding OAEP Padding happens when either the input string for the decrypt is not exactly the same as the output string of the encrypt, or because the public key used for encryption does not match the private key used for decryption.

In your case, you are not actually passing an encrypted string to the Decrypt method so it will absolutely always fail, essentially making the encryption and decryption key not match.

Comment: Well encoding is part of encryption if you see the encryption method above.

Comment: @user2913184 Your encrypt method won't work. You cannot encrypt and decrypt with the private key. You encrypt with the PUBLIC key and decrypt with the PRIVATE key. Please read how RSA works before trying to do this.

Comment: Sorry I did it with public key just copy pasted the code from decrypt method into encrypt method and changed it's name though forgot to change PrivateKey to  PublicKey.Key.